# ucwords but ignore words what are in BLOCK capitals?

Tags: php, string

I was wondering how to format the strings below to uppercase first letter of words but ingore words that are in uppercase already.

Examples

```
ABcd Efg = Abcd Efg
abcd EFG = Abcd EFG
```

Could someone please give an example if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex to filter the words by allupercaseiness would be an option:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b(?![A-Z]+\b)\w+\b/e', 'ucwords("$0")', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using `$words = ucwords($words)` should work for you.

Comment: Wrong, it wont make 'Abcd' from 'ABcd'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "abcd DefGH IJK";
$arr = explode( " ", $string );
foreach( $arr as &$word )
  if( $word != strtoupper($word ) )
    $word = ucfirst( strtolower( $word ) );
$string = implode( " ", $arr );
echo $string;
```

Result: `Abcd Defgh IJK`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to evaluate each word separately:

```
if( strtoupper($word) != $word ){
    $word = ucwords($word);
}
```

This means splitting any strings on spaces and evaluating each part separately.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a working example:

```
// put these into an array to demo the logic
$s1="ABcd Efg";
$s2="abcd EFG";
$words_array = array($s1,$s2);

foreach( $words_array as $words ){
    echo "Old words: $words\n";

    // inline replace of words
    $split_words = explode(" ",$words);
    for( $i=0; $i<count($split_words); $i++ ){
        $word = $split_words[$i];
        if( strtoupper($word) != $word ){
            $split_words[$i] = ucwords(strtolower($word));
        }
    }
    echo "New words: ".implode(" ",$split_words)."\n";
}
```